# calling a socket server written in C++ in a client python code with subprocess doen't work properly

Tags: python, c++, sockets, subprocess, popen

I have a server code written in C++ and a client code written in python. Now, I want to run the server code on the background while the client python code is executed. I use subprocess.Popen to call the C++ server code, which i complied with g++ server_min.cpp -o server.

If I run this two programs in separate teminals, they work perfeclty.

```
import socket
import subprocess, time, os, io, sys, stat, copy
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 4456
ADDR = (IP,PORT)
SIZE = 1024
FORMAT = "utf-8"
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
       
    print("This is client!!!!!")
    ep = 0
    while(True):
        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client.connect(ADDR)
        data = client.recv(SIZE).decode(FORMAT)
        print(f"[SERVER] {data}")
    
        if(ep == 4):meg = "Done"
        else: meg = "Continue...ep="+str(ep)
        client.send(meg.encode(FORMAT))
        client.close()
        
        if(meg == "Done"): break
        ep+=1
        
    print("End Program!!!!!")
    print("*******************************************************")
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 4456

int main(){
    
    //Variables and structures
    int server_fd, client_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    socklen_t addr_size;
    char buffer[1024];

    // Server socket
    server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); //create the server socket

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
    listen(server_fd, 5);
    printf("[LISTENING] Port number: %d\n", PORT);
    
    while(1){
        
        client_fd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_size);
        printf("[CONNECTED] New Connection\n");
        
        strcpy(buffer, "Hello, this is a test message");
        send(client_fd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
        
        memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
        recv(client_fd, buffer, 1024, 0);
        printf("[CLIENT] %s\n", buffer);
        
        if(strcmp(buffer,"Done") == 0){
            close(client_fd);
            printf("[DISCONNECTED] Process Done \n");
            break;
        }
        
        close(client_fd);
        printf("[DISCONNECTED] Connection closed \n");
    }
    shutdown(server_fd, SHUT_RDWR);
    return 0;
}
```

However, once I call the server code within the python and run the python code in the same terminal. The code crashed.

```
import socket
import subprocess, time, os, io, sys, stat, copy
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 4456
ADDR = (IP,PORT)
SIZE = 1024
FORMAT = "utf-8"
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #calling the server 
    run_pro = subprocess.Popen('./server', shell=False, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) 
    sys.stdout.flush()
    
    print("This is client!!!!!")
    ep = 0
    while(True):
        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client.connect(ADDR)
        data = client.recv(SIZE).decode(FORMAT)
        print(f"[SERVER] {data}")
    
        if(ep == 4):meg = "Done"
        else: meg = "Continue...ep="+str(ep)
        client.send(meg.encode(FORMAT))
        client.close()
        
        if(meg == "Done"): break
        ep+=1
        
    run_pro.wait()
    print("End Program!!!!!")
    print("*******************************************************")
```

And I received the following error.

```
This is client!!!!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client_min.py", line 19, in <module>
    client.connect(ADDR)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
[LISTENING] Port number: 4456
```

What should I do? Your help will be very much oblighed!

Comment: TCP isn't message oriented. If you send 100 bytes and try to receive 100 bytes, you may receive 4, then 8, then 88 because there is no concept of a message.